# mysql command line non terminating statements

Tags: mysql, unix

Sometimes my queries from the command line will never terminate. I feel as if it happens at random as well.

This isn't just for show warnings... It does it on selects too.

```
mysql> show warnings
    -> ;
    -> ;
    -> 
    -> 
    -> psaef 
    -> p[wkt 0=23kit 0
    -> -=13i t0=13i -=13i  1- 1  -   1
```

Just did it again...

```
mysql> select trigger_schema, trigger_name, action_statement from information_schema.triggers ;
    -> 
    -> 
    -> 
    ->
```

Comment: I suspect you accidentially paste something into your terminal. Maybe a sensitive touchpad on your laptop?

Comment: Did a previous line contain a "delimiter" statement?

Comment: I am working with triggers yes, But I am sourcing them, not typing them in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the scripts you source in end with:

```
DELIMITER ;
```

If you're not sure, then type that in yourself after sourcing them.